# How to loop through a certain token from a json object?

Tags: c#, winforms, json.net

I need to read a json file in c# (winforms) but I am having some troubles doing so.

this is a simplyfied contents of the file :
it contains 2 routes, each route has a one leg and one or more steps

```
{
"routes" : [
  {
     "legs" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "246 km",
              "value" : 246047
           },
           "steps" : [
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "2.4 km",
                    "value" : 2383
                 },
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "3.7 km",
                    "value" : 3697
                 },
              },
           ],
        }
     ],
  },
  {
     "legs" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "280 km",
              "value" : 280048
           },
           "steps" : [
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "2.4 km",
                    "value" : 2383
                 },
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "6.9 km",
                    "value" : 3697
                 },
              },
           ],
        }
     ],
  }
],
}
```

What I need to do is :
1. find the shortest route (this I managed to do)
2. loop through the steps of the shortest route, this I dont know how

my code for finding the shortest route is this :

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(content);
JToken token = null;

decimal distance = 0;
decimal shortest = 0;
JToken routes = o.SelectToken("routes");

foreach (JToken tempToken in routes.Children())
{
    distance = (decimal)tempToken.SelectToken("legs[0].distance.value") / 1000;
    if (distance < shortest || shortest == 0)
    {
        shortest = distance;
        token = tempToken.SelectToken("legs[0]").First;
    }
}
```

After this code, shortest contains 246047 so this works.
But the variable token contains all the legs for this file, not just the first leg of the shortest route.
I was hoping to end up with a varable token that only contained the steps for the leg of the shortest route, so I could loop through this token.
Maybe I have it all wrong and it just does not works like that ?

How can I loop through the steps of the shortest route ?

EDIT :
I tried another approach but with same results.
This is my second approach :

```
int index = 0;
foreach (JToken tempToken in routes.Children())
{
    distance = (decimal)tempToken.SelectToken("legs[0].distance.value") / 1000;
    if (distance < shortest || shortest == 0)
    {
        shortest = distance;
        token = o.SelectToken("routes[" + index.ToString() + "].legs[0]");
    }
    index++;
}
```

After this, the variable token still contains all the legs of all routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It will let you loop through the steps of the shortest leg

```
        foreach (JToken tempToken in routes.Children())
        {
            distance = (decimal)tempToken.SelectToken("legs[0].distance.value") / 1000;
            if (distance < shortest || shortest == 0)
            {
                shortest = distance;
                IEnumerable<JToken> steps = tempToken["legs"].Children()["steps"].Children();

                foreach (JToken step in steps)
                {
                    var thisStep = step;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: cant compile "foreach (JToken step in steps)", the compiler sais : foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'var' because 'var' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: updated answer you need IEnumerable<JToken> steps instead of var steps